# Polymer: Changing value of an observer property without notifying the observer

Tags: event-handling, polymer, polymer-1.0, observers

The scenario is preventing the change of value under certain conditions. For this purpose, I found the **observer** function itself as the best location to check for change.

But making changes to the value of the property in the observer results in calling the observer again turning into a black hole.

```
properties: {
        foobar: {
                type: String,
                observer: 'foobarChanged'
        }
},

foobarChanged: function(oldValue, newValue) {
        if(!matchesCertainCondition(newValue))
                this.foobar = oldValue;
}
```

But, I am not able to come up with a straight forward solution. Is there any way for doing this in Polymer 1.x?

Is there a reason why should they fire a change event to the observed value within the observer itself?

Workarounds are also welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an observer, this problem could be solved with a [`computed property`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers#define-a-computed-property) based on another public property. The computed property would detect all changes to the public property, validate the input value, and optionally return a different value.

In this example, the computed property `_index` computes a value based on `index`, with a maximum of `100`.

```
// template
<div>[[_index]]</div>

// script
Polymer({
  is: 'x-foo',
  properties: {
    index: Number,
    _index: {
      computed: '_computeIndex(index)'
    }
  },
  _computeIndex: function(index) {
    return Math.min(index, 100);
  }
);
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties: {
      index: Number,
      _index: {
        computed: '_computeIndex(index)'
      }
    },
    _computeIndex: function(index) {
      return Math.min(index, 100);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo index="200"></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <div>index: [[index]]</div>
      <div>_index: [[_index]]</div>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/BLggBw?editors=1010)

Comment: This is not going to work. Because computed properties restricts me from using two way bindings :(

Comment: You could probably set a flag before resetting the value in your observer. e.g., `this._changing = true; this.foobar = 2; this._changing = false;`. Your observer would return early if `this._changing` is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need it to work with 2-way data binding, I figured out a (fairly gross) workaround. Just make your property an object, with a boolean key-value representing a toggle or flag telling you whether it was changed by an internal or external event. This is similar to the other answerer's comment, but is asynchrony-safe.
This looks something like the following:

```
properties: {
  foobar: {
    type: Object,
    notify: true,
    value: {
      value: 'blah',
      internalToggle: false
    },
    observer: '_foobarChanged'
  }
}
```

...

```
_foobarChanged: function(oldfoobar, newfoobar) {
    if (oldfoobar.internalToggle != newfoobar.internalToggle) {
      return
    }
    if (oldfoobar.value != newfoobar.value) {
      // Do stuff
      if(!matchesCertainCondition(newfoobar.value))
        this.foobar = {value: oldfoobar.value, 
                       internalToggle: !oldfoobar.internalToggle};
      }
    }  
}
```

Gross as hell, but it works. Honestly at this point it's almost worth abandoning polymer's 2-way binding, and just splitting into multiple properties.